# ReactJS + Material Design: How to get theme colors outside component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, themes, material-design, chart.js

In my ReactJS `app.js` I defined a theme:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: "#54BD40",
        },
    },
});
```

I am using the [React wrapper for Chart.js](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2) and I want to set-up a chart graph. But I am not sure how I can use the primary/main color from my theme:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

let data = []; //data here
const MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mrt', ...];
const WEEK = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', ...];

let chart = {
    labels: MONTHS,
    datasets:[{
        borderColor: ['#XXX'], //THEME COLOR HERE
    }],
};

class LineChart extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData: chart,
            usage: false,
            generation: true,
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Line data={ this.state.chartData } options={} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LineChart;
```

For using theme palettes inside `render()`, I know I can import `withTheme()` and use `this.props.theme`. But how this work now outside the component? (I just started using ReactJS)

Answer (score 2):

Well as I understand you can import constant into your main js file after doing 
**export** in app.js. Example.  -

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({ palette: { primary: { main: "#54BD40", }, }, });
```

Then import

```
Import { theme } from "app"
```

And use it anywhere in your main js file.